# Android service that was running when the phone was shut down starts automatically when the phone is booted

Tags: android, service

I am currently developing an Android telephony application that includes a service to handle all the SIP signaling for making and receiving calls.

I want this service to start exclusively when the user has correctly logged into the application. However, I am observing an undesired behavior: if the device is shut down while the app is running, the service is automatically started after the phone boots. This does not happen if the application is closed at the moment of shutting down the phone.

I have been reading about it but no answer comes up. Could anybody explain why this happens and how to prevent it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post your manifest and the source to the `BroadcastRecever` that you are using to listen to `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcasts. The only way a service starts up is if somebody starts it, and the OS will not do that on its own.

Comment: I was preparing myself to post the manifest and explain that I had no BroadcastReceiver implemented (as a I don't want my service to automatically start) when I found out that one of the receivers of the application was declaring an intent-filter with the action android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.

Thanks to your comment I have quickly discovered that this behaviour was being done on purpose, without me knowing it. It was inherited as an undocumented feature from a former version of the software.

Thank you so much, CommonsWare, for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CommonsWare comment I have quickly found the answer:

> [...] The only way a service starts up is if somebody starts it, and the OS will not do that on its own.

I was so blinded thinking the OS was responsible for it that I didn't notice it was being done on purpose, as an undocumented feature inherited from a former version of the app.

There was a BroadcastReceiver listening to the android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED action. This receiver was, among other things, restarting the service on start up when the app had not been properly shut down.

Thank you CommonsWare for your help.

---

*Update*

After preventing the BroadcastReceiver from listening to the BOOT_COMPLETE action, I still experience the same behavior.

The reason is that this BroadcastReceiver is also listening to connectivity changes to restart the SIP service when the WIFI or a data connection becomes active, only when the app is running. Wether the application was closed or not is stored in the app preferences, but this value was not properly set when the phone was shut down while the app was running.

That is why the service was still unwantedly starting on boot: because the BroadcastReceiver detected an android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE at start up and the preference telling wether the app was still running or had been quit was not properly updated.

Comment: im saving the state if a service has to be started on boot in sharedPrefs and my onBootListener checks if it is true or false and decides whether to start or not to start the service. It should work around your problem and is failsafe!

Comment: As I have afterwards updated, that is exactly what this app does, and that was the root of the problem: the state if the service has to be started was not correctly saved in SharedPrefs when the phone was shut down while the application was still running. Thank you bofredo for your comment.